# Is there much change in python code when I want to change the database from sqlite to postgres?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

So far I've been using sqlite with django, however I might want to deploy it to heroku and therefore use postgresql instead. Other than installing postgres, connect it to my app and repopulate it with the same data, are there any necessary change in my python code? For example the models, queries to get the data, lines that perform adding data to my database, and so on. Does those things need change or is the syntax still the same?

Comment: Short answer, everything will probably work the same (probably). Without more information about how you are using the data you store and information about what data types you are using we can't definitively answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using specific Django ORM's features like manual SQL queries etc, it's straightforward to migrate to a different db.

You need to change the `DATABASE` config and its `ENGINE` entry to `django.db.backends.postgresql`.

Of course, you need to test it after db change and before deployment.
For more see [supported engines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/settings/#engine) and [databases details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/databases/)